# Closed form of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, closed-form, exponential-sum

I am looking for a closed form of the following convergent series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda^2)^n}{(6n+i)!}$$
For the case of $i=0$, the answer is ready, but when $i=1,2,3,4,5$, everything gets crazy.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything gets crazy"?

Comment: The standard trick is to evaluate $\sum \frac{x^n \xi^n}{n!}$ for $\xi$ the various sixth-roots of unity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to "skip terms" in a power series is to use roots of unity. Here, let $\zeta=e^{i\pi/3}$ be a primitive $6$th root of unity, so that
$$
\frac16 \sum_{j=0}^5 (\zeta^\ell)^j = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } 6\mid \ell, \\ 0, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, setting $\alpha=e^{i\pi/6}$, for any $0\le k\le 5$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda^2)^n}{(6n+k)!} &= (\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^{-k} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^{6n+k}}{(6n+k)!} \\
&= (\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^{-k} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^m}{m!} \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } 6\mid (m-k) \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \Big\} \\
&= (\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^{-k} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^m}{m!} \frac16 \sum_{j=0}^5 (\zeta^{m-k})^j \\
&= \frac16 (\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^{-k} \sum_{j=0}^5 \zeta^{-jk} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha\lambda^{1/3}\zeta^j)^m}{m!} = \frac16 (\alpha\lambda^{1/3})^{-k} \sum_{j=0}^5 \zeta^{-jk} \exp(\alpha\lambda^{1/3}\zeta^j).
\end{align*}